# How to use two ng-repeat inside a particular tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a json and inside this json there is an array that I want to iterate in `<td>`.
My functionality is like I have to create a table based on user input. User provides input for number of rows, input columns and output columns. So I have three arrays i.e $rootScope.input_columns, $rootScope.output_columns and $rootScope.rows which contain data provided by user to create the table. Now in input_columns there's an array which contains some information which I need to show on row cell. But with my current code it is giving me blank row.

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('rulesApp');

app.controller('myController2', ['$scope', '$rootScope',function($scope, $rootScope){
var inputcol=[];
            $rootScope.input_col=$scope.no_of_input;
            $rootScope.output_col=$scope.no_of_output;
            $rootScope.rows=$scope.no_of_row;
            for(var i=0;i<$rootScope.input_col;i++){
                inputcol.push({
                    id: inputcol.length,
                    dropped: false,
                    dataType:'',
                    name:'',
                    type:'input',
                    path:'',
                    rowCellValue:[],
                    rowCellValueOutput:[]
                });
            }$rootScope.input_columns=inputcol;//here i get input_columns json, Similarly json are made for output_columns and rows
            $scope.statementSelected = function(branch, selected_branches) {
        if(branch.selected) {
            for(var i = 0; i < $rootScope.input_columns.length; i++) {  
//Here i add an array inside input_columns.rowCellValue     $rootScope.input_columns[i].rowCellValue.push($rootScope.rows[i].rowCellValue);
                    }
})
```

Adding the structure of input_columns

[image]

This is my html code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows"><!--It iterates on row json -->
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <!--Here i want that in row cells input_columns.rowCellValue data gets populate on row cell for input column -->
        <td ng-repeat="col in input_columns.rowCellValue">{{(col == "") && "&lt;enter data&gt;" || (col.split("/")[3])}}</td>
        <!--Here i want that in row cells output_columns.rowCellValueOutput data gets populate on row cell for output column -->
        <td ng-repeat="col in output_columns.rowCellValueOutput" ng-click="openDialog($event)">{{(col == "") && "&lt;enter data&gt;" || (col.split("/")[3])}}</td>              
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to get a structure like this
[image]

But I am getting blank rows
[image]

Please can anyone help me in this task. Is there an issue that I haven't iterated input_columns so i am not getting input_columns.rowCellValue values. How can I get the values of input_columns.rowCellValue in table columns? Is there anyway that I can use two ng repeat, with first ng-repeat i can get input_column value[col in input_column] and with second ng-repeat i can get rowCellValue[cell in col.rowCellValue].?

I was trying some solution and figured out one way to access rowCellValue:

This is the modified html code

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows"><!--It iterates on row json -->
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <!--Here i want that in row cells input_columns.rowCellValue data gets populate on row cell for input column -->
<!--here with $index i am getting first value of rowCellValue in entire column can i iterate it with using rows length -->
            <td ng-repeat="col in input_columns">{{(col.rowCellValue[$index] == "") && "&lt;enter data&gt;" || (col.rowCellValue[$index].split("/")[3])}}</td>
            <!--Here i want that in row cells output_columns.rowCellValueOutput data gets populate on row cell for output column -->
            <td ng-repeat="col in output_columns" ng-click="openDialog($event)">{{(col.rowCellValueOuput[$index] == "") && "&lt;enter data&gt;" || (col.rowCellValueOutput[$index].split("/")[3])}}</td>    

        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

this the actual table I want for input_column:
[image]

But I am getting this: 
[image]

Can i iterate col.rowCellValueOutput[$index] with row length instead of $index? and for each column. If yes, please suggest some approach for this.

Comment: can you please fiddle it out.

Comment: Are you getting errors on the web console?

Comment: You have `$rootScope.row` in your code but it should be `$rootScope.rows` for the ng-repeat to work.

Comment: No, i am not getting any error on the console.

Comment: it is $rootScope.rows only.. I edited the code :)

Comment: Added a plunker to give an idea of what i am trying to achieve http://plnkr.co/edit/9SUvLDaev6MvNGAvJDTC?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem:

```
<td ng-repeat="col in input_columns" title="" id="{{col}}">{{(col.rowCellValue[$parent.$index] == "") && "&lt;enter data&gt;" || (col.rowCellValue[$parent.$index].split("/")[3])}}</td>
```

In controller structure of json was like:

```
input_column({
rowCellValue[
0:dic2317/fdgdfg3535/accViolation
1:dic2317/sdg3436dg/driver
})
```

I used $parent.$index for iterating with rows index.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting this into a JSON object and looping through the JSON. It looks like what you are trying to do is, everytime a new row is created, the `inputCol` and `outputCol` would be trying to output everything for every row.

```
//pseudo code
ng-repeat row in rows
    ng-repeat input in inputs
    ng-repeat output in outputs
```

Everytime you loop through `rows`, all of `inputs` and `outputs` data will be outputted again, making every row the same.

If you made a JSON object and done something like,

```
ng-repeat row in rows
    ng-repeat input in row.input
    ng-repeat output in row.output
```

Your JSON would look like

```
var rows = [{ input: [ "row1", "col2" ], output: [ "col3", "col4" ] },
            { input: [ "row2", "col2" ], output: [ "col3", "col4" ] }];
```

Comment: Actually i have done code like this, because if i add any row or input_column or output_column then i should be able to add a new row and when i delete any row or column then that particular row/column with all the values should get deleted. If i use the code suggested by you then upon adding any new inputcolum the data gets shifted to left and column with header is added at the last

Comment: Have you tried using an `ng-if` to check that the number of inputs is equal to the number of input columns? If there is a new column to make it three, and only 2 inputs, call a function to pass a blank column. Or you can just add a blank element into the `input` element.

Comment: No i haven't used ng-if, when add_input_column is clicked at that that I add a blank element in input_columns. with this a header is created.. but the number of columns is based on the number of rows created that's why in tr I have used ng-repeat row in rows. But the issue I am facing is I want to set some values in table cell and that is why i created an array inside input_column to fetch value from it and to set it. for this i want to run ng-repeat twice in td which i am not getting how to do